# React onSubmit only shows value on the next submit

Tags: reactjs

I am building a todo app and my form has an input element in it where the value is stored in a state variable. The form should submit that value to an array but when I press submit it doesn't show and only shows the value when I try to submit another value., and so on and so on.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = inputValue;
    if (name === "") return;
    setTodos((prevTodos) => {
      return [...prevTodos, { id: name, name: name, isComplete: false }];
    });
    console.log(todos);
    setInputValue("");
  };
  return (
    <main>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="todo-input"
          placeholder="Create a new todo..."
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you tell us where did you write the code to show `todos`?

Comment: just a simple project I want to make,to learn more about code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of this question. please look into it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected. Your todos array is updated in the onSubmit function, however, you are not able to view this change.

If you wrote:

```
useEffect(() => console.log(todos), [todos])
```

You'll see 'todos' updating as you'd expect

Comment: okay thank you very very much